# c# find mail by from mail

Tags: c#, outlook, email, restrict

How to find items in Outlook inbox by from email?

This version works and finds email:

```
String sCriteria = "[From] = 'Sebastian Nowak'";
Outlook.Items filteredItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(sCriteria);
```

This version doesn't work, doesn't find any mail:

```
String sCriteria = "[From] = 'mymail@mydomain.com'";
Outlook.Items filteredItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(sCriteria);
```

How do I should search by email from which mail was sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you are looking for is:

```
inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress]='mymail@mydomain.com'");
```

confirmed using Outlook 12.0 library using VS2005